# Don't display php fatal errors - It messes with my JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm making a AJAX call to a PHP script **outputing JSON**. When PHP displays fatal errors, it invalidates my beautiful JSON output.

The JSON string becomes prefixed with `↵Fatal error: Call to undefined function iDontExist() in /path/to/place/whereErrorOccured.php on line 80↵`

I've tried everything I can possible think of... alas, here we are:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', false);


function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = '', $errline = 0, $errcontext = array()) {


    global result;

    // do stuff... 

    http_response_code(200);
    $json = json_encode($result);
    echo $json;
    exit;

}

function fatalHandler() {
 $error = error_get_last();
 if($error) errorHandler($error["type"], $error["message"], $error["file"], $error["line"]);
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
register_shutdown_function("fatalHandler");
```

*One note that may or may not help:* The AJAX call is method POST. The PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is set to allow the call to me made.

Have .htaccess set as follows as well

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0
```

**UPDATE:** `display_errors` was being reset by an included script. Fatal errors still cause JSON output to be prefixed with a single space. Currently using `trim()` to get rid of it, which is more of a hack than complete fix. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks [@AzizSaleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935500/aziz-saleh) for the `phpinfo()` suggestion.

Comment: If you don't want a Fatal error to be displayed, fix the Fatal error.

Comment: That's not the point... There is no REAL error. I've made the error on purpose ( hence: iDontExist() ) so if a real fatal error occurred, it would be outputted inside my JSON the AJAX call is expecting. Not outside where it invalidated my JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Errors that happen on compilation time cannot be catched by setting display_errors and error_reporting in the script. Use the `.htaccess` file for that:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0
```

Comment: Possibly your webspace is not configured to have `.htaccess`s interpreted.

Comment: No it is, I use `.htaccess` all the time.

Comment: Perhaps PHP is running via cgi though, and not as an apache module (which means you'd have to edit the php.ini).

Comment: Added `php_value error_reporting 0` for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @Siguza, I've just edited the php.ini file as well. Still no luck.

Comment: @MilkMan Use `phpinfo()` to detect what the configs are and where they are coming from.

Comment: @AzizSaleh, just tried that: 
`display_startup_errors = off` , 
`display_errors = off` , 
`html_errors = off` ,
`error_reporting = 0`

Comment: @AzizSaleh just checked it again, just before function instead of at the start of the script. Your suggestion worked. The value is reseting itself somewhere, I still need to find where. Although the error still causes a single space. I'm using trim() as a hack for now. Any thoughts?